# ArcMap commands .NET code equivalent

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, vb.net

What is the .NET code equivalent for this general ArcMap command syntax:

```
Application.Document.CommandBars.Find(ArcID.Query_ClearSelection).Execute()
```

I have been using this one below as a work around, however it is much more code than what I would like to use.

```
Dim pUID As New UID
Dim pCmdItem As ICommandItem
'Use the GUID of the Save command
pUID.Value = "{AB073B49-DE5E-11D1-AA80-00C04FA37860}"
'or you can use the ProgID
'pUID.Value = "esriArcMapUI.MxFileMenuItem"
pUID.SubType = 3
pCmdItem = m_App.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID)
pCmdItem.Execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's about the best way that you can do it (that I know of).

You might be able to tack on Execute at the end of your pCmdItem assignment, i.e.

`pCmdItem = m_App.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID).Execute()`

but that's the only "optimization" I can think of. A lot of overhead is taken care of when you're using ArcMap rather than ArcEngine.

Comment: So, there is not a newer variation to the "ArcID" built-in module, becuase this only existed within ArcMap VBA?

Comment: @artwork21 Not to my knowledge. GUIDs and ProgIDs are all I've ever used to access tools on the toolbar.